# Is there a way to extract an integer from a database using the sqlite3 Python3.x module?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

When I attempt to extract the desired data it is returned as:
[(26.0),]
Obviously this is a list, however when I then extract this piece of data it is a touple.

```
def calculatewage(self):
    employeeID = self.employee1.get()
    employeehrs = self.employee1hrs.get()


    with sqlite3.connect("ProjectDatabase") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        code = """SELECT HourlyRate FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID = '{0}'""".format(employeeID)
        cursor.execute(code)
        output = cursor.fetchall()

    print(type(output))
    output = output[0]
    print(output)

    return
```

The result:

```
[(26.0),]
(26.0),
```

Comment: That's how it [works](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall). `cursor.fetchone()` would omit the list arround. `print(output[0][0])` prints your number.

Comment: Thank you Maurice, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To performing queries on SQLite I am using this `select()` function, which return `pd.DataFrame`. Most of the time when you run query output is table, so `DataFrame` format looks as the most reasonable choice.

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


def select(query: str, db: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    with sqlite3.connect(db) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        cols = [description[0] for description in cur.description]
        return pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns=cols)
```

Where `query` is valid SQLite query as string, and `db` is path to sqlite database, or you can use `:memory:` databse.

**Simple example:**

```py
result = select(query="SELECT 1 Col1,'aa' Col2", db=":memory:")
print(result)
```

If there is any need you can easily transform `DataFrame` to `dict` using pandas [build in function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) `to_dict()`.

**Transform output to** `dict`**:**

```py
result = select(query="SELECT 1 Col1,'aa' Col2", db=":memory:")
print(result.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

**Transform column to** `list`**:**

```py
result = select(query="VALUES (1), (2), (3)", db=":memory:")
print(result['column1'].to_list())
```